# array_map inline anonymous function

Tags: php, array-map

I tested inline anonymous function with `array_map` [here](http://3v4l.org/fSi8P)

and it worked but when I tried same with **$user_meta** it is not working.

```
$user_meta = Array ( [interest] => Array ( [0] => Array ) [type] => 
     Array ( [0] => Array ) [user_status] => Array ( [0] => deny)
     [firstname] => Array ( [0] => ) [lastname] => Array ( [0] => B ) 
     [email] => email@cc.com ) 

$user_meta = array_map(function($a) { return $a[0]; },$user_meta);
```

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in"

[here is the test link showing error](http://3v4l.org/Z8iS4)

Comment: Your definition of the $user_meta array is not valid for a PHP array, it's print_r() output, formatted for human readability

Comment: P.S. inline anonymous functions only work in  PHP 5.3+

Comment: @Paulpro why did you rollback the format change?

Comment: problem in in the email! need to put that in quotes "email@cc.com"

Answer (score 113):

I hope this will help:

```
$user_meta = array_map(function ($a) { return $a[0]; }, $user_meta);
```

Comment: This is a good answer, except the remark `there must be a space between the keyword function and its parameters`. Because i removed the space and got no problem.

Comment: The space after `function` keyword really doesn't matter...!

Comment: The space changes nothing.

Comment: Yes, the syntax seems fine. There error should be from $user_meta definition.

Answer (score 18):

There's nothing wrong with the `array_map` line, but everything before it is wrong. That is the output of a `print_r` not PHP code. Compare how you define the array in the two links you posted.

Comment: I am getting same error when I pass the array with arguments..I could only make it work by calling function explicitly.. [here](http://3v4l.org/F0Sac)

Comment: Which version of PHP do you have? Most people have at least 5.3 now, and you're code worked fine in 5.3 and up.

Comment: I am using php 5.5 only you can check the updated link..again it is showing errors

Comment: @BLPraveen There are no errors in the section titled: `Output for 5.3.0 - 5.5.1`. Only in the older version sections.

Comment: @BLPraveen Added some output so you can see that's it's working: http://3v4l.org/5NgCc

Comment: The array syntax is fine... `array('0' => '')` is just going to define an associative array with a key '0' pointing to an empty string. The error's almost certainly just that he's on a PHP version older than 5.3.

Answer (score 10):

Slightly shorter could be

```
$user_meta = array_map(fn ($a) => $a[0], $user_meta);
```

But I would prefer the `array_column` approach for such an `array_map`

Answer (score 3):

**That's not an answer to your question**, but since you want to return the first key of each sub-array, you can just use `array_column`.

```
$user_meta = array_column($user_meta, 0);
```